# Examples of unbounded pseudo-differential operators in $L^{\infty}$

Tags: reference-request, harmonic-analysis, pseudo-differential-operators

During my graduate studies I've been told that pseudo-differential operators with symbols in $S^0=S^0_{1,0}$ (the simplest class) are bounded $L^2 \to L^2$, and also $L^p \to L^p$ for all $p \in (1, \infty)$. I have also heard that such  pseudo-differential operators need not be bounded $L^{\infty} \to L^{\infty}$. But no counter examples were presented to me and I can't find any counter example in any book I came across. The Hilbert transform (in Fourier space $\widehat{Hf}(\xi)=i\operatorname{sgn}(\xi) \;\hat f (\xi)$) is unbounded $L^{\infty} \to L^{\infty}$ but strictly speaking it is not a standard pseudo-differential operator.

> What are the canonical examples of zeroth order pseudo-differential
>   operators that are not bounded $L^{\infty} \to L^{\infty}$?

If there is a "standard" reference dealing with this problem I would be glad to know where to read it, but any relevant reference would be great!

Comment: Can't you just take a smooth version of $\textrm{sgn}(\xi)$? The modification can of course be done by a compactly supported (in $\xi$) perturbation, so this will be bounded on $L^{\infty}$ and thus you still have a counterexample.

Comment: This is true and answers the question... I should have seen it before!
However a better question is the following: is there a more general class of pseudo-differential operators unbounded on $L^{\infty}$?